# Given a system in $\mathbb{F}_2$ in RREF, how do I find a solution of minimal norm?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, search-algorithms, discrete-mathematics, linear-algebra

I have a $12 \times 12$ (so not really large) system of linear equations in $\mathbb{F}_2$ which I got to RREF through the usual row reduction. Suppose the system has multiple solutions, and call the unknowns $x_i$. What is the least expensive way to find a solution that minimizes the amount of $x_i$'s such that $x_i = 1$, or equivalently, a solution of minimal norm? Is this solution unique?

Comment: Well if it is homogenous the 0 is your answer.  But if you want to ignore that then no it wont be unique, a null space with basis $\langle (1,0,1),(1,1,0)\rangle$ exists and has no nonzero vector of hamming weight 1.

Comment: No, it is not homogenous.